# Why is 12 Grimmauld Place in the middle of a Muggle neighborhood?

Tags: harry-potter

The Blacks were shown to be very anti-Muggle. Their house has anti-Muggle spells placed on it. Yet, their house is placed in a Muggle neighborhood, with a Muggle number.

Why?

Comment: Kudos for trying to expand the collective knowledge of the community, just watch out for other people who had the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

J.K. Rowling answered this in a Twitter interview: https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/563635069102080000

> A Black ancestor coveted the beautiful house, so 'persuaded' the Muggle occupant to leave & put the appropriate spells on it.